# Unity Plugin for both iOS and Android Failing AOT for iOS due to AndroidJavaObject

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a Unity plugin that will work both on iOS and Android.
I have two point of entry to my plugin, one class for iOS and another for Android.

The problem is when I use only the iOS class and try to build the XCode project from Unity I get this error:

The class UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject could not be loaded, used in UnityEngine

AndroidJavaObject class is used only in the Android class which is never referenced by the unity scripts.

The problem is I want to provide one plugin that will "just work" for both iOS and Android. The plugin is compiled so I can't use any of the unity pre-processor flags.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no alternative to conditional compilation if you need access to the native API. I would suggest to use encapsulate plugin access by using an interface, for example:

```
public interface IMyPlugin
{
    void Do ();
}

public class MyIOSConnector : IMyPlugin
{
    public void Do () {
#if UNITY_IOS
        // iOS implementation
#endif
    }
}
public class MyAndroidConnector : IMyPlugin
{
    public void Do () {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        // Android implementation
#endif
    }
}
public static class MyPlugin
{
    static IMyPlugin _myPlugin = null;

    public static IMyPlugin Access {
        get { 
            if (_myPlugin == null) {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                // maybe this needs special handling e.g. a dummy implementation
#endif
                switch (Application.platform) {
                case RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer:
                    _myPlugin = new MyIOSConnector ();
                    break;
                case RuntimePlatform.Android:
                    _myPlugin = new MyAndroidConnector ();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            return _myPlugin;
        }
    }
}
```

From other classes you call then:

```
MyPlugin.Access.Do ();
```

Comment: I've end up using this solution. In my case I'm compiling most of the plugin code into DLL and I've left only the parts that need to be #ifdef as .cs files.

Comment: As a side note, I would expect Unity 3D to not even reference the Android plugin in an iOS build if you have placed it unter Assets/Plugins/Android. That is at least what the documentation suggests: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html and http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Special_Folder_Names_in_your_Assets_Folder#.22Plugins.2FAndroid.22 etc. But it does not work this way obviously, and iOS references Android plugin assemblies. See also this possible related post: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ios-build-loads-assembly-from-assets-plugins-android-why-build-fails.320670/